# What Limits the power of a typical LED

Tags: led

So, you can buy 20mW LEDs and you can buy 10W LEDs. What are the construction differences between these? Is it only the heat dissipation?

If I took a 5mm 20mW LED, ground the plastic down from the back (while keeping the die intact), and mounted the metal inside really well to a super effective heat-removal-system, would I be able to run it at 10W continuously?

Comment: I think all of the 10W LEDs I've ever seen are actually an array of LEDs. Something like 3S3P.

Comment: ... or 9s1p but I don't think this is the point. Compare to 1W power LED.

Comment: I think there should be some differences in the crystal struture, so it can handle larger currents AND dissipate the excessive heat to the substrate. Having a very thin and small crystal would make large differences in temperature between junction and substrate and however you try to cool down the substrate you won't be able to cool down the junction itself.

Comment: Have dunked a 20mW 5mm red LED into liquid nitrogen for cooling, then turned up the current till destruction. It took over an ampere for awhile, nitrogen bubbling & boiling away from the metal leads, where most of the heat comes out (not through the clear plastic).

Comment: How bright was it?

Comment: Can only judge "brightness" by eye (not a reliable instrument). It certainly got brighter at high current, but it appeared that optical efficiency didn't scale linearly - going from 0.5A to 1A didn't double "brightness".

Comment: @glen_geek But did it double bubble?

Comment: @AndrewMorton lol. Its an interesting thermal problem applicable to nuclear reactors too. Bubbles reduce area contact of leads-to-coldliquid, which reduces heat transfer. It was too hard to see sites where bubbles started. I suspect the one lead onto which the LED chip is bonded (vs. the other lead to which a skinny bonding wire is attached) transferred most heat. So perhaps not much double-bubble;-) Am surprised that skinny bonding wire didn't open.

Answer (score 3):

Just going to the question of dissipation, diamond is probably where things are headed in the nearer term with LEDs. Diamond's thermal conductivity (usually treated by the phonon model for lattice vibrations) is about \$2200\:\frac{\textrm{W}}{\textrm{m}\cdot \textrm{K}}\$ -- which is many times that of copper or any other metal at ordinary temperatures and pressures and a hundred times as good as sapphire.

Look up DIW (diamond islands wafers), CVD (continuous vapor deposition), and DLC (diamond like carbon) to get an eye into where things are currently at, I suspect.

Also, licensing for high brightness LEDs are extremely narrow/tight. A few companies own key IP (Nichia's YAG phosphor, for example.) And they are locking things up pretty tight, right now. (I worked at OSRAM for a while. Since I know how to develop and manufacture new phosphors in heated quartz chambers, and have extensive datasets on the last 50 years of phosphor studies and development, I've considered getting back into this business... but the barriers are high and I'd need the right partners here.)

But like the old saying goes, "It's only as strong as its weakest link," transporting heat away is only as good as the poorest conductor in the chain. So you need to hook up good conduction with good conduction or the whole thing falls on its face. And even with diamond, the weakest link will still be right at the GaN itself that generates the light. So novel designs may need to work on "diamond like" emitting lattice structures, eventually. I'll look forward to seeing that development.

Comment: Which reminds me of the other night when one of those random passing thoughts that plague my head appeared and I wondered how long it will be before some bright spark (pun intended) figures out how to build in a white LED behind the diamond in an engagement ring just to make it sparkle that much brighter like they do under the lights in the store when you buy them.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the maximum current spec is mostly a function of how much heat the die and package can dissipate.  Note that for high power LEDs, heat sinking is required to operate them at full current.

If you were to mount a 20 mW LED die on something that can carry away a lot of heat, you probably could run it at more than 20 mW.  However, there are heat transfer limits in the die itself.  That means even if you keep one surface of the die at some fixed temperature, at some power level other parts of the die will be too hot.

The overall construction will also only be good up to some current.  Eventually there will be failures like melting bond wires.